# click() is not working in python selenium for 'a' tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

while scraping the paginated website i wanted to load the second page. But when i stored the paginated elements in the list and then clicking on it gives an error

```
next_page_div = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pages')
next_page_tags = next_page_div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
# There was 10 numbers as 'a' tag so i stored it in the list

print(next_page_tags[3].click())
```

**Error :**

```
kishor@ubuntu:~/Coding/Web-scraping$ python -u "/home/kishor/Coding/Web-scraping/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kishor/Coding/Web-scraping/main.py", line 86, in <module>
    print(next_page_tags[3].click())
  File "/home/kishor/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 93, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/kishor/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/kishor/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/kishor/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="/python-jobs-..." class="">4</a> is not clickable at point (623, 832). Other element would receive the click: <div class="privacyPolicy">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.64)
```

I want to go on every page of the site and scrape the data from it.

Comment: check if the paginated elements that you've stored in a list are proper, I may be able to help if you can provide the URL you're targeting (if possible)

Comment: the url is : https://www.naukri.com/python-jobs?k=python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, the solution is to scroll down upto the height of the pagination tab

```
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="content"]')))
# scroll down to the height of the pagination tab
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 5400);")


next_page_div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="fleft pages"]')
next_page_tags = next_page_div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
print(next_page_tags[3].click())
```